# PowerShell: Convert an object to a string

Tags: powershell

We have Exchange Info Stores that begin with UsersA-B, UsersC-D, etc., and then some that are outside that naming convention.

```
$allIS = Get-MailboxDatabase |
             Where { $_.name -notlike "*Users*" } |
             Select Identity
```

I'll lookup a current user's info store, and then try to do a comparison on the $allIS array. If it matches, do some action.

When I output the value of $allIS[0] for instance, it returns `@{Identity=MSCCR\CEO\CEO}`.

I'd like to throw those converted strings into a different array, and then do the comparison. This would be to have a dynamic list of information stores to compare against. But maybe this isn't the best, most efficient way. What would be the best way to try to do this comparison, as right now I'm comparing apples to oranges here?

Comment: I did a Split-Path on the $allIS variable and was able to do a concatenation to do the string comparison.  Probably not an elegant way to do it, but it works.

Comment: This `$allIS | % {[string]$_.Identity}` will convert all objects in the array to strings. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that does it too!  Thanks Gebb!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is hard to tell if that could be optimized without seeing the second part...

But it's pretty easy to get a flat array of identities. Either use `-ExpandProperty` on select, or use `foreach { $_.Identity }` instead of select:

```
$allIS = Get-MailboxDatabase | ? { $_.name -notlike "*Users*" } | select -expand Identity
$allIS = Get-MailboxDatabase | ? { $_.Name -notlike '*Users*' | foreach { $_.Identity}
```

Comment: I swear I'd already tried both of those options before, but oh well, all good now.  Thanks BartekB!

Answer (score 1):

#### The PowerShelly way

```
$isNames = @()
$allIS = Get-MailboxDatabase | 
    Where { $_.name -notlike "*Users*" } | 
    Select Identity | 
    %{ $isNames += $_.name }
```

It pipes the output to a `foreach` loop using `%` instead.

#### A more procedural way

```
$isNames = @()

foreach ($is in $allIS)
{
    $isNames += $is.identity
}
```

That gives you a simple array of only the names of the information stores, as strings instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use "property dereference operator" '.' for a property that is not a member of the array class, it will dereference each element of the array instead.

```
$allIS = (Get-MailboxDatabase | ? { $_.name -notlike "*Users*" }).Identity
```